# Git - track external project

Tags: git

I have a git repository, say `abc`, which is at `master` now.
I downloaded (using [go get](http://golang.org/cmd/go/) command) another package, say `xyz` (since GOPATH is set to the root of the project, newly installed package is inside the project abc).

So, now I have an external project within my project, both managed through git. I checked in my project, but none of the files in the eternal project `xyz` is not part of main project (master). What is the best way, and how, I can treat the external project as a part of my main project?

Thanks.

---

EDIT: I have been reading about gitsubtree. It looks like it is a solution to my problem, but not sure how to use it. Do you think subtree is an option, and is it possible to make `xyz` a subtree of main project `abc`

Comment: is this a go related question? If yes, you should tag it as such, if no: Use git subtree or git submodules.

Comment: thanks for the comment. It is not go related, and I could get it work. Not sure is the properway, will add it.

Answer (score 0):

I used subtree, and hope this is the best way.

```
 git subtree add --prefix=src/github.com/.../xyz https://github.com/../xyz.git master
```